# Is this space an indescrete space?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be an infinite set and $\tau$ a topology on $X$ with the property that the only infinite subset of $X$ which is open is $X$ itself. Is $(X,\tau)$ an indiscrete space?

My train of thought is that because $X \in \tau$ and it's infinite, if there is another subset $S_1$, $X\cap S_1 \in \tau$ and it is infinite, it is of course open, so $X\cap S_1 =X$. If the intersection is finite but non-empty, I have no arguments against it belonging into $\tau$, so $(X,\tau)$ should not be indiscrete.

However, the question is so perplexing to me that I can't confirm by myself whether I'm right or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is false. Take $X = \mathbb{N}$ with the topology $\{\mathbb{N},\varnothing,\{0\}\}$.

Also, notice that $X\cap S_1= S_1$ as $X$ is the whole space, and so $S_1$ is a subset. So, the intersection can't be finite if $S_1$ was infinite to begin with.